# How to synchronize text between Monaco Editor and a Docker container's file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ide, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I'm developing an online IDE similar to CodeSandbox, utilizing Docker for running code in a sandboxed environment and Monaco Editor as the frontend for code editing.

I need assistance with managing the synchronization of text between the Monaco Editor and the corresponding file within the Docker container. Currently, my approach involves inserting a script into the container that is triggered by the server whenever changes are made to the text document. This script then updates the associated file accordingly.

However, I'm encountering challenges with implementing certain Monaco Editor features in the shell script, which could become cumbersome. The Monaco Editor provides extensive editing capabilities, and I'm unsure how to efficiently handle all the supported features in my synchronization process.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to achieve seamless synchronization between Monaco Editor and the Docker container's file while ensuring that the Monaco Editor's editing capabilities are properly accounted for in the synchronization mechanism.